# assigning an alternative value to pandas dataFrame conditional on its value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, element, rows

I am trying to assign alternative values to a column in a pandas dataFrame object. The condition to assigning an alternative value is that the element has value zero now.

This is my code snippet:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,0], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == 0.0:
        df.iloc[i]['A'] = df.iloc[i-1]['A'] + df.iloc[i]['B'] - df.iloc[i-1]['B']
```

However, as it turns out, the values in these elements remain zero! The above has zero effect.

What's going on?

Comment: There's possible bug in your code. When `i=0`, then `df.iloc[i-1]` return last row of dataframe. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original answer below works for some inputs, but it's not entirely right. Testing your code with the dataframe in your question, I found that it works, but it's not guaranteed to work with all dataframes. Here's an example where it doesn't work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=list(range(0,12,2)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

This dataframe will cause your code to fail because the indices are not 0, 1, 2... as your algorithm expects, they're 0, 2, 4, ..., as defined by `index=list(range(0,12,2))`.

That means the values of `i` returned by the iterator will also be 0, 2, 4,..., so you'll get unexpected results when you try to use `i-1` as a parameter to `iloc`.

In short, when you use `for i, row in df.iterrows():` to iterate over a dataframe, `i` takes on the index values of the dimension you're iterating over *as they're defined in the dataframe*. Make sure you know what those values are when using them with offsets inside the loop.

---

Original answer:

I can't figure out why your code doesn't work, but I can verify that it doesn't. It may have something to do with modifying a dataframe while iterating over it, since you can use `df.iloc[1]['A'] = 0.0` to set a value outside a loop with no problems.

Try using [`DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) instead:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == 0.0:
        df.at[i, 'A'] = df.iloc[i-1]['A'] + df.iloc[i]['B'] - df.iloc[i-1]['B']
```

This doesn't do anything to account for `df.iloc[i-1]` returning the last row in the dataframe, so be aware of that when the first value in column A is 0.0.

Comment: Yes, this works indeed.

If you ever figure out why my code is not working, I'd appreciate it really well if you let me know!

Comment: actually, the pandas documentation advises against this approach: see [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas-dataframe-iterrows)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 This isn't the approach that that's warning against. You shouldn't attempt to modify the `row` that the iterator returns.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,0], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
df['A'] = df.where(df[['A']] != 0, 
                   df['A'].shift() + df['B'] - df['B'].shift(),
                   axis=0)['A']
print(df)

     A  B
0  NaN  1
1  1.0  2
2  2.0  3
3  3.0  4
4 -3.0  1
5  1.0  2
6  1.0  3
7  2.0  4
```

The NaN is there since there is no element prior to the first element

Comment: This comes closer! However, this operation does everything at once always referring to column 'A' in the old dataframe, while we want it to pick up values in 'A' that have already been assigned new values, such that the value for 'A' in row i uses the newly assigned value for 'A' in row i-1.

Would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `chained indexing` which is related to the famous SettingWithCopy warning. Check the SettingWithCopy setting in [modern pandas](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1-intro) by Tom Augspurger.

In general this means that assigments of the form `df['A']['B']= ...`are discouraged. It doesn't matter if you use a loc acessor there.

If you add print statements to your code:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    print(df)
    if row['A'] == 0.0:
        df.iloc[i]['A'] = df.iloc[i-1]['A'] + df.iloc[i]['B'] - df.iloc[i-1]['B']
```

you see strange things happening. The dataframe `df` is modified if and only if the first row the column 'A' is 0.

As Bill the Lizard pointed out, you need a single accessor. However, note that Bill's method has the disadvantage of providing label based access. This may not be what you want when having a dataframe that is differently indexed. Then a better solutions would be to use loc

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['A'] == 0.0:
        df.loc[df.index[i], 'A'] = df.iloc[i-1]['A'] + df.iloc[i]['B'] - df.iloc[i-1]['B']
```

or iloc

```
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['A'] == 0.0:
            df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('A')] = df.iloc[i-1]['A'] + df.iloc[i]['B'] - df.iloc[i-1]['B']
```

assuming the index is unique in the last case.
Note that the chained indexing occurs when setting values.

Though this approach works, it's - by the quote above - not encouraged!

Comment: There are *so many* pitfalls when modifying the data you're iterating over. Check out my updated answer, I fell right into one.